# Ansible module_stdout: command not found when using sudo on Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, ansible, sudo

I am connecting to centos 7 virtual and physical machines using ansible with a user called ansible that has passwordless sudo permissions on all the boxes. On most machines it works, but on one box I get this error:

`FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to ... closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "/var/tmp/sclpbsoCZ: line 8: -H: command not found\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
    "rc": 127
}`

I set up passwordless sudo using advice from this link:
https://code-maven.com/enable-ansible-passwordless-sudo
(basically, edit /etc/sudoers to let user ansible sudo without a password)

I thought these machines were identical, but obviously something is amiss.

Adding -vvv to the ansible-playbook command lets me see that the command it is trying to run is:

`'/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '`

How is it that this one machine isn't working with ansible?

Answer (score 2):

I found this, but at first blush it seemed unrelated to ansible:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192809/sudo-i-returns-an-error

It turns out that centos has scl (software collections) that can be enabled.

I had devtoolset-7 enabled at boot:

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/

This happens to wrap sudo with a script that doesn't seem to actually handle all of the options of the original sudo. It seems like this could be considered a bug  (or at least bad behavior) in devtoolset-7.

For now the fix was to remove the entry in /etc/profile.d/ that was enabling the devtoolset-7.

It was running this code:

`source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable`

If I ssh'd into the machine and ran the offending command:

`sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh`

It would give me the same error:

`# sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh
/var/tmp/sclKpdWFR: line 8: -H: command not found`

And pointed me to the problem when I queried which sudo was being used...

`# which sudo
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/sudo`

What a rabbit hole!

Comment: This is also true with `devtoolset-8`!  Of course if your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` are using `source scl_source enable devtoolset-8` or similar you can't disable it once you're in a shell.  You have to comment it out of the file that's running it at shell creation (as you mentioned).  I was unable to use `become_exe: /usr/bin/sudo` to override the sudo Ansible used but someone else may have more luck.

Comment: I was also able to patch the devtolset-7 sudo to work correctly. It's insane to me that RedHat took the risk to replace sudo with a hacky script. I won't even post the hacky fix, but it is possible. This would allow you, @Dan, to get ansible to work without restarting the shell, but really... ick.